# Converter uma Object em ArrayList<Visitante>

Tags: java, android

Tenho um metodo que retorna valores do `firebase`. Quando recebido, crio um novo `ArrayList<Visitante`> e o salvo em um `Object`.

```
ArrayList<Visitante> visitantes = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            visitantes.add(snapshot.getValue(Visitante.class));
                            Log.e("***", snapshot.getValue(Visitante.class).getNome());
                        }
event.emit(new Result(visitantes));
```

`event.emit()` espera um tipo `Object`.

Como que transformo novamente esse Object para o `ArrayList<Visitante>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça o *cast* de `object` para `ArrayList<Visitante>`.

```
array = (ArrayList<Visitante>) objecto;
```

Se o objecto não for do tipo indicado será lançada uma excepção do tipo `ClassCastException`

Comment: em seu if ele mostra um erro em ArrayList<Visitante>: Ilegal generic type instanceof

Comment: mas o cast deu certo! Mas só uma pergunta antes de escolher como a resposta certa, Se o array que foi atribuido em object for modificado, o novo array que o recebe de objeto será atualizado? ou seja, ele passa a referencia?

Comment: Devido ao *type erasure* não é possível usar `instanceof` dessa forma. Teria de ser assim: `objecto instanceof ArrayList<?>` e depois verificar o tipo do item. Não coloquei na resposta porque julgo que o indicado é a excepção ser lançada. Sim é passada a "referência".